# Insert multiple rows into a table with a trigger on insert into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-insert

I am attempting to create a T-SQL trigger that will essentially insert *x* number of rows into a third table based upon the data being inserted into the original table and data contained in a second table; however, I'm getting all sorts of errors in the select portions of the insert statement.

If I comment out this portion `[qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[columnID] in (select columnID from [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns])`, IntelliSense gets rid of all the red lines.

Table designs:

- `Users` table - contains user info
- `skillColumns` table - list of all columns possible, filtered on the `productGroupID` of the user
- `Skills` table - contains the data per user, one row for every `columnID` in `skillColumns`

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Users_INSERT 
   ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT into [qmgmt].[dbo].[Skills]([userID], [displayName], [columnID]) 
    Select [iTable].[userID], 
           [iTable].[displayName], 
           [cID] in (select [columnID] as [cID] from [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns])
    From inserted as [iTable] inner join 
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns] on 
        [iTable].[productGroupID] = [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[groupID]
END
GO
```

Is what I'm looking to accomplish even possible with a trigger? Can multiple rows be inserted into a table with the `in` keyword?

---

## UPDATE:

After using the answer provided by J0e3gan, I was able to create a trigger in the opposite direction:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_skillColumns_INSERT_Users
    ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns]
    AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INTO [qmgmt].[dbo].[Skills]([userID], [displayName], [columnID])
    Select [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users].[userID],
           [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users].[displayName],
           [iTable].[columnID]
    From inserted as [iTable] inner Join 
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users] on
        [iTable].[groupID] = [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users].[productGroupID]
    Where
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users].[userID] in (select [userID] from [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users])
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with an `AFTER` trigger.

The column list is not the correct place for the `IN` criterion that you are trying to use, which is why it is underlined in red.

Try adding the `IN` criterion to the `JOIN` criteria instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Users_INSERT 
   ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT into [qmgmt].[dbo].[Skills]([userID], [displayName], [columnID]) 
    Select [iTable].[userID], 
           [iTable].[displayName], 
           [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[columnID]
    From inserted as [iTable] inner join 
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns] on 
        [iTable].[productGroupID] = [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[groupID] and
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[columnID] in (select columnID from [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns])
END
GO
```

Alternatively add it to a `WHERE` clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Users_INSERT 
   ON [qmgmt].[dbo].[Users]
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT into [qmgmt].[dbo].[Skills]([userID], [displayName], [columnID]) 
    Select [iTable].[userID], 
           [iTable].[displayName], 
           [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[columnID]
    From inserted as [iTable] inner join 
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns] on 
        [iTable].[productGroupID] = [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[groupID]
    Where
        [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns].[columnID] in (select columnID from [qmgmt].[dbo].[skillColumns])
END
GO
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate then? if I have the `in` in the wrong place, please help me out in learning the proper placement.

Comment: @BrandonB: Absolutely - was getting to that. :} I added a couple restructurings to consider.

Comment: Brilliant! I chose to use the `in` in the Where clause because I was able to read it easier in my head, and since I have quite a few of these triggers that I need to write, readability will be a key factor.

Thanks again for the fast response, if I could "up vote" this answer again, I would do it in a heartbeat.